# Программа выдает не то, что нужно

Tags: c++, указатели

По условию нужно найти в строке симметричный фрагмент вида "abcdcba" длиной 7 и более символов (не содержащий пробелов) и возвращает указатель на его начало и длину.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int* f10(char* c, int& dlina)
{
    int* index = NULL;
    int k = 0, l = 1, ns, max = 0;
    char previous = c[0];
    for (char* p = &c[1]; *p != '\0'; ++p, l++)
    {
        char next = *p;
        if (next != previous)
            break;
        else
            k++;
        if (k > 2 && k > max)
        {
            max = k - 1;
            *index = l - max;
            dlina = 2 * max + 1;
            return index;
        };
        previous = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    const int n = 500;
    char c[n] = "salqwertrewqdz";
    int dlina = 0;
    int* x = f10(c, dlina);
    if (x != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Индекс " << x << " Длина " << dlina;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Не найдено > 7");
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

Выдает не то, что нужно: `Индекс 00000061 Длина 0`

Comment: Сначала  `int* index = NULL;` а потом `*index = l - max;`. Нельзя разыменовывать нулевой указатель.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно заменить `int* index = NULL;` на `int* index = new int;`. И.к. разименование nullptr ни к чему хорошему не приводит.